# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Int Error when loading typesafe configuration

Tags: akka, typesafe-config

I have akka project.

This is application-1.conf at src/resources folder.

```
akka {
  loglevel="INFO"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
     hostname = "127.0.0.1"
     port = 2552
   }
    log-sent-messages=on
    log-received-messages=on
 }
}
```

Below is my action at package example7_2 at folder src/main/scala/example7_2.

```
package example7_2

import akka.actor.Actor
class SimpleActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => println(s"I have been created at 
    ${self.path.address.hostPort} and received message $msg")
 }
```

}

I have the Main App `HelloAkkaRemoting10` below.

```
package example7_2

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object HelloAkkaRemoting10 extends App {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("HelloAkkaRemoting1", ConfigFactory.load("application-1"))
}
```

When I run the application, I get the

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Int
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Int
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:74)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]         at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.$anonfun$getClassFor$1(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:21)
[error]         at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]         at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:20)
[error]         at akka.serialization.Serialization.$anonfun$bindings$3(Serialization.scala:313)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$map$2(TraversableLike.scala:739)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:231)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:462)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:738)
[error]         at akka.serialization.Serialization.<init>(Serialization.scala:311)
[error]         at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:15)
[error]         at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:880)
[error]         at akka.actor.ExtensionId.apply(Extension.scala:77)
[error]         at akka.actor.ExtensionId.apply$(Extension.scala:77)
[error]         at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.apply(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
[error]         at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:203)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:796)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:793)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:793)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:809)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:244)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:287)
[error]         at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:262)
[error]         at example7_2.HelloAkkaRemoting10$.delayedEndpoint$example7_2$HelloAkkaRemoting10$1(HelloAkkaRemoting10.scala:7)
[error]         at example7_2.HelloAkkaRemoting10$delayedInit$body.apply(HelloAkkaRemoting10.scala:6)
[error]         at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
[error]         at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
[error]         at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
[error]         at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]         at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
[error]         at example7_2.HelloAkkaRemoting10$.main(HelloAkkaRemoting10.scala:6)
[error]         at example7_2.HelloAkkaRemoting10.main(HelloAkkaRemoting10.scala)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error]         at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:89)
[error]         at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:83)
[error]         at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:73)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]         at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error]         at sbt.Run$.executeTrapExit(Run.scala:120)
[error]         at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:73)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunMainTask$6(Defaults.scala:1130)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunMainTask$6$adapted(Defaults.scala:1125)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:359)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:282)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (chapter7/compile:runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Oct 18, 2017 11:11:52 AM
```

Other miscellaneous details -

sbt version - 1.0.2
scala version - 2.12.3
akka version - 2.5.4

Looks to me ConfigFactory load is throwing error but not sure the exact root cause. Please let me know if I am missing any configuration.

Comment: I'm not using sbteclipse plugin at all.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in sbt that has nothing to do with Typesafe Config and only slightly with Akka, I have filed it as https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3736

Comment: hi Arnout - Any updates on this. The sbt issue that you mentioned is already closed and it doesn't have much details on it.

Comment: The sbt issue is still open, but I'm not aware of anyone actively working on it. The workaround for now would be to go back to sbt version 0.13.16.

Comment: Someone just commented on that issue: another workaround might be to configure `fork in run := true`.